# AJAX Script Crashes browser

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post

Im trying to submit user register information with AJAX like this:

```
<script>

$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
event.preventDefault();
var supplied_username = $('#desired_username').val();
var password = $('#password').val();
var email_address = $('#email_address').val();



$.post("register", { desired_username: desired_username, password: password, email_address: email_address } ,
function(data){
    $('body').append(data);
});
});
</script>
```

The return data is simply a string of text (i.e. Success! or Register problem....). I think that the script must be infinitely looping somehow but Im not sure where or why. The backend works perfectly when I pass normal POST data to it without AJAX. That is why I think it must be a problem with the client side. Any ideas what could be going on here?

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct? You are posting to `[current_url]/register`. Can you see the request being fired on your js console? Can you see the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've left out some stuff.  I think the code below is what you're looking for

```
<script>

$("#submit_btn").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var supplied_username = $('#desired_username').val();
     var password = $('#password').val();
     var email_address = $('#email_address').val();



    $.post("register", { desired_username: supplied_username, password: password, email_address: email_address } , function(data){
           $('body').append(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: In this case, I think `window.event` will be available anyway - see http://jsfiddle.net/K2JTR/

Comment: I don't believe it will.  I believe you need to include this when the callback is made.

Comment: Dan, I thought that too. But then (a) why does my jsfiddle work (it logs the event); and (b) why isn't the form just submitted normally?

Comment: @bfavaretto - lose jsfiddle and do it the way the documentation says to do it.  I looked at jsfiddle today and it does use the callback, but only when it is needed ie: event.preventDefault (they used "e.preventDefault).

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't it be better to append it within a proper text tag (`<p>` or anything else) and inside the `document`, instead of the `body` directly?

Comment: Sure, but do you think that would affect the crashing problem?

Comment: +1 .append() expects the data to be HTML, and tries to parse it as HTML. It needs to be wrapped in something (either from the server or after receival).

Answer (score 1):

I once tried running AJAX on client-side with no succes, then tried the same code server-side with success. May that be the case?

Also, if I looked correctly, you're passing wrong variables. You create a `supplied_username` and pass a `desired_username`. May that not be the problem?